# Reflect.getOwnMetadata is not a function with karma-typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, aurelia

I am trying to unit test (with Karma + Jasmine + [karma-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-typescript)) my TypeScript project. The project structure is as follows:

```
root
|- src/*.ts              //all TypeScript source files
|- tests/unit/*.spec.ts  //all spec (test) files
|- karma.conf.js
|- tsconfig.json
```

My `karma.conf.js` looks like following:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', "karma-typescript"],
    karmaTypescriptConfig: {
      tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json"
    },
    files: [
      'src/*.ts',
      'tests/**/*Spec.ts'
    ],
    exclude: [],    
    preprocessors: {
      "**/*.ts": ["karma-typescript"]
    },
    reporters: ["progress", "karma-typescript"],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

My spec file looks like below:

```
import 'aurelia-polyfills'; //<- importing this, as the project have dependency on Aurelia
// import "babel-polyfill";
import "reflect-metadata";
import "jasmine";
import { Utility } from './../../src/Utility';

describe("this is a try to set up karma-jasmine-webpack test (TS)", () => {
    it("utility_test", () => {        
        const result = Utility.doSomething();
        const expected = Expected_Result;
        expect(result).toEqual(expected);
    });
});
```

But when I run `karma start`, I get

```
Chrome 55.0.2883 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ERROR
  Uncaught TypeError: Reflect.getOwnMetadata is not a function
  at C:/Users/spal/AppData/Local/Temp/karma-typescript-bundle-16376WqjdFvsYtjdI.js:2325
```

I assume, that it is because of pollyfill(s) is/are not being loaded in the browser. However, I have `import`ed `aurelia-pollyfills` in my spec file.

Please suggest how this can be corrected.

---

**Update:** Anyone looking at this for answer, might also face issues with source map (`Error: Could not find source map for:''`) from `karma-remap-istanbul` trying to generate coverage report.

One way to avoid this problem is to simply remove the problematic reporter plugin. For example, change `reporters: ['mocha', 'coverage', 'karma-remap-istanbul']` to `reporters: ['mocha', 'coverage']`.

Other solution would be to generate the source maps. In case you can't specify the same in your `tsconfig.json`, you can specify that in `karma.conf.js` if you are using `karma-typescript`:

```
karmaTypescriptConfig: {
  tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json",
  compilerOptions: {
    sourceMap: true
  }
}
```

Lastly, I ended up with `reporters: ["mocha", "karma-typescript"]`, as it shows which test passed, and which failed, as well as generate a coverage report.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably missing the `reflect-metadata` import:

> $ npm install --save-dev reflect-metadata

Then add the following to your `files`:

```
files: [
    { pattern: "node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js", include: true },
    { pattern: "src/*.ts", include: true },
    { pattern: "tests/**/*Spec.ts", include: true }
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems to work, as that error is gone now (but facing other related to sourcemap; ignoring it by using `reporters: ['mocha', 'coverage'],`). However, I would like to understand, why we need to explicitly include that file, as I have already imported the same in my spec file. Guess it is not bundled by default?

Comment: reflect-metadata is designed to be used a global that's why needs to be imported as a global